# How to process XML in PySpark?

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks XML package to read and process Wikipedia XML data, however, am not sure how to handle a nesting.

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='page').load(data)
```

I read in the data using the above command and set rowTag to page to get all pages information.

The data looks something like this for one page:

```
<page>
<title>User talk:Jroset24</title>
<ns>3</ns>
<id>63975912</id>
<revision>
  <id>957023082</id>
  <timestamp>2020-05-16T16:11:47Z</timestamp>
  <contributor>
    <username>HostBot</username>
    <id>16596082</id>
  </contributor>
  <comment>/* Jroset24, you are invited to the Teahouse! */ new section</comment>
  <model>wikitext</model>
  <format>text/x-wiki</format>
  <text bytes="1237" id="968918613" />
  <sha1>isokyoojfzhgql1po9r1qmctdfscv59</sha1>
</revision>
<revision>
  <id>959350629</id>
  <parentid>957023082</parentid>
  <timestamp>2020-05-28T10:41:03Z</timestamp>
  <contributor>
    <username>TheImaCow</username>
    <id>38905475</id>
  </contributor>
  <comment>Your draft page has been moved ([[WP:DFY|DFY]])</comment>
  <model>wikitext</model>
  <format>text/x-wiki</format>
  <text bytes="1987" id="971274481" />
  <sha1>bm5i6af24vvqq1vk0ajnc1wrnvp7ix3</sha1>
</revision>
<revision>
  <id>970319036</id>
  <parentid>959350629</parentid>
  <timestamp>2020-07-30T16:16:22Z</timestamp>
  <contributor>
    <username>Rich Smith</username>
    <id>13314572</id>
  </contributor>
  <comment>declined ([[WP:AFCH|AFCH]] 0.9.1)</comment>
  <model>wikitext</model>
  <format>text/x-wiki</format>
  <text bytes="5059" id="982346934" />
  <sha1>15rvufxszc80p75iwuzysyfxq2hz9u3</sha1>
</revision>
```

For this one single page, I have three revisions, observe the tags. What I am aiming as an end table is so that I can store it in a database:

```
Title, Time, Revision
```

I am not utterly sure how to process this data and get the right information in to a structured dataframe

Comment: Please take a look at this article: https://q15928.github.io/2019/07/14/parse-xml/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `page` has a `title` multiple `revision`s, and each has a `timestamp`. If you just let it infer the schema, you should find that `page` has `revision` as an array of structs containing revisions, and a `title`.

What are you seeing that is different?